# i am having issue on adjusting layout on android when soft keyboard appears on screen

Tags: android

i am having problem in adjusting layout on android, when the keyboard appears on the screen, half of the webview hides under keyboard i want it to adjust itself
my code so far is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundmap"
    tools:context="com.example.adeel.abc.newmessage">

            <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/messengerWeb">
            </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and code in manifest file is

```
<activity android:name=".newmessage"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    </activity>
```

Can i have tried many solutions on stackoverflow but non of them are working and 
webview doesnt adjust itself
kindly please help me in making my code better
Thanks alot 
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the activity's windowSoftInputMode attribute to:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```